Passing large Data in Navigationextras in router.navigate Angular 16 causing Error in Firefox
I have a problem with "router.navigate(['some-url'], extras).
In this extras object I have a state in which a list is passed that can be of different sizes.
if i pass a small list < 500 items, then it works smoothly in firefox and chrome.
Now I have a case with a list of 17k items and then it only works in chrome.
In firefox I get an error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [Exception... "Illegal value"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: https://some-url/main.e9ce4132b9234a49.js :: 103/l_/I :: line 3"  data: no]

In firefox the router.navigate... crashes...
I dont know what i can try, but i expect that it works in both browsers

Firefox has a limit of 640k characters in the state object.

Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be
restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit
of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object.
If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger
than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception. If you
need more space than this, you're encouraged to use sessionStorage
and/or localStorage.

